# How do i load a certain view using zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I'm following the guide to load a view as in this link : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.introduction.html

However, I'm not sure where to keep the booklist.php file that is the view file to be loaded. So, I kept it inside the /views folder (outside the scripts folder)

But, I'm getting this error :

```
An error occurred

Application error
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this question in the comments at the bottom of that page.  'Steve' says:

You have to tell it where to find the view script:

so create the `booklist.php` file in `application/views/scripts/books` and insert the line:

```
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/scripts/books');
```

after

```
$view = new Zend_View();
```

in your controller script.

Comment: Does zend automatically render view ?